# cohomology of $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]

Above is a way to find the cohomology groups of $S^1$. But what I do not get is how they concluded that $\delta$ is surjective. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: It follows from the exactness at $H^1(S^1)$, and the mentioned fact that $H^1(U) \oplus H^1(V) = 0$.

Comment: I am sorry I am still not seeing the connection of that with the /exactness of $H^1(S^1)$. Could you explain a little more if you do not mind

Comment: Nope that is fine I got it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict yourself to :
$$
... H^0(U \cap V)  \xrightarrow{\delta} H^1(S^1) \xrightarrow{i} H^1(U) \oplus H^1(V) ...
$$

By exactness at $H^1(S^1)$, we have that $\ker i = \operatorname{im} \delta$. However, note that $H^1(U) \oplus H^1(V) = \mathbf 0$, so that $i$ is taking every element of $H^1(S^1)$ to $0$. Hence, the kernel of $i$ is the whole of $H^1(S^1)$, so the image of $\delta$ is also $H^1(S^1)$, which is the whole space, so $\delta$ is surjective.

A dual result is also true : If we have an exact sequence (with groups as objects and homomorphisms between them) like :
$$
\mathbf 0 \xrightarrow{i} I \xrightarrow{\delta} J ...
$$

Then by exactness at $I$, you can prove that $\delta$ is *injective*,since $\ker \delta  = \operatorname{im} {i} = \mathbf 0$. You will need to apply these facts many times in your study of cohomology, I can tell you that much from a brief study of cohomology from Hatcher.

Comment: I am a little surprised by one thing : you must have done homology before this, and that involved Mayer Vietoris of it's kind, and so you must have seen plenty of examples of this happening. Is that true, or have you never seen this phenomena?

Comment: Kinda got thrown into learning this. I know some homology but I never came across Meyer Vietoris when I studied Homology. But I understand it much better now. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$\ldots \to X  \underbrace{\to}_{\delta} H^1(S^1) \to 0$ means that the image of $X$ is the same as the kernel of the map out of $H^1(S^1)$, which being the zero map is the whole $H^1(S^1)$